# Does my code run 1000 instances of 1000 iterations of my non linear recursive equation?

Tags: cuda

from my understanding of CUDA C each thread executes an instances of the equation. but how do i print out all the entire values. the code actually works but really need someone to review it for me please to confirm my result is actually inline with what i set out to design.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cutil.h>

__global__ void my_compute(float *y_d,float *theta_d,float *u_d)
{
    int idx=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*gridDim.x;

    for (idx=7;idx<1000;idx++)
    {
        y_d[idx]=theta_d[0]*y_d[idx-1]+theta_d[1]*y_d[idx-3]+
            theta_d[2]*u_d[idx-5]*u_d[idx-4]+theta_d[3]+
            theta_d[4]*u_d[idx-6]+theta_d[5]*u_d[idx-4]*y_d[idx-6]+
            theta_d[6]*u_d[idx-7]+theta_d[7]*u_d[idx-7]*u_d[idx-6]+
            theta_d[8]*y_d[idx-4]+theta_d[9]*y_d[idx-5]+
            theta_d[10]*u_d[idx-4]*y_d[idx-5]+theta_d[11]*u_d[idx-4]*y_d[idx-2]+
            theta_d[12]*u_d[idx-7]*u_d[idx-3]+theta_d[13]*u_d[idx-5]+
            theta_d[14]*u_d[idx-4];
    }
}

int main(void)
{   
    float y[1000];
    FILE *fpoo;
    FILE *u;
    float theta[15];
    float u_data[1000];
    float *y_d;
    float *theta_d;
    float *u_d;

    cudaEvent_t start,stop;
    float time;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    // memory allocation

    cudaMalloc((void**)&y_d,1000*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&theta_d,15*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&u_d,1000*sizeof(float));
    cudaEventRecord( start, 0 );

    // importing data for theta and input of model//

    fpoo= fopen("c:\\Fly_theta.txt","r");
    u= fopen("c:\\Fly_u.txt","r");

    for (int k=0;k<15;k++)
    {
        fscanf(fpoo,"%f\n",&theta[k]);
    }
    for (int k=0;k<1000;k++)
    {
        fscanf(u,"%f\n",&u_data[k]);
    }

    //NB: pls does this for loop below make my equation run 1000000
    // instances as oppose to the 1000  instances i desire?
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)  
    {
        //i initialised the first 7 values of y because the equation output
        //starts form y(8)

        for (int k=0;k<8;k++)
        {
            y[k]=0;

            cudaMemcpy(y_d,y,1000*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            cudaMemcpy(theta_d,theta,15*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            cudaMemcpy(u_d,u_data,1000*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

            //calling kernel function//
            my_compute<<<200,5>>>(y_d,theta_d,u_d);
            cudaMemcpy(y,y_d,1000*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        }
        printf("\n\n*******Iteration %i*******\n", i);
        //does this actually print all the values from the threads? 

        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            printf("%f",y[i]);
        }
    }
    cudaEventRecord( stop, 0 );
    cudaEventSynchronize( stop );
    cudaEventElapsedTime( &time, start, stop );

    cudaEventDestroy( start );
    cudaEventDestroy( stop );
    printf("Time to generate:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

    cudaFree(y_d);
    cudaFree(theta_d);
    cudaFree(u_d);
    fclose(u);
    fclose(fpoo);
    //fclose();
    _getche();

    return (0);

}
```

Comment: You might want to take some care of properly formatting your code. Especially the indentation. If you take a look right now, you'll notice that it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

> how do i print out all the entire values.

Well, you can copy it to host (which you do already) and print it out normally?

However, I am worried about your code for several reasons:

- Only the threads belonging the same warp are executed truly in parallel. A warp is a collection of 32 adjacent threads. (something like `warpId = threadIdx.x/32`). Threads belonging to different warp can execute in any order, unless you apply some synchronization functions.
- Because of the above you cannot say much about `y_d[idx-1]` when computing `y_d[idx]`. Was `y_d[idx-1]` already computed/overwritten by the other thread or not?
- You have only 5 threads in your block (<<<200,5>>>), but because blocks can be launched at warp granularity (multiple of 32), it will just keep 5 threads running and 27 threads idling for each block you launch.
- You are not using parallelism at all! You have a `for` loop which will be executed by all the 1000 threads. All 1000 threads compute exactly the same thing (modulo the race conditions). You compute the thread index `idx`, but then completely ignore it and set `idx` to 7 for all threads.

I would strongly suggest --- as an exercise for launch configuration, synchronization, thread indexing --- implementing a parallel [prefix-sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) algorithm, and only after confirming that it works correctly, doing this more advanced stuff...

Comment: Thanks for the observations.y[idx-1] was  initialised to 0, and due to all the past inputs being set to 0, the for loop start from 7. I will take off the for and make the block<<<5,200>>> if thats ok. i'm actually new to cuda c. i have got a limited time to grasp this whole stuff and complete my project work on cuda c hence all these questions. many thanks

Comment: I understand the limited time, but I think you will really be better trying to code something simpler first. Despite language similarities, writing parallel code in CUDA requires a different way of thinking than single-threaded C code. In your case - it doesn't matter if loop starts from 7, from 0 or from 42. The fact that you use the loop index and not thread index defeats the purpose of using CUDA whatsoever! Sure, you can have some loops in the code, but you should have your threads do different stuff at some point...

Comment: please is it ok for you to rewrite the aspect of the code you're referring. so i'm 100% clear on it. thanks.

Comment: Firstly, I am not 100% sure what you want to do. Secondly, if you want to iterate a formula 1000000 times and the next step directly depends on the previous values you will have to do exactly that sequentially. CUDA parallelism won't help you with that. But if an iteration step involves some independent computation - that can be helped. Thirdly, I fear most of the code would have to be rewritten; but I don't want to solve complete problems from beginning till end.

Comment: OK, I will rewrite the code and show it to you again if that's alright. i'm actually looking execute a 1000 iterations of a 1000 similar equations, hence this code is a lead up. Once i get this sorted the next phase will be having all the 1000 parallel have completely different inputs.

Comment: @CgynusX1 I just uploaded the modified code will appreciate if you can point out what i'm doing wrong this time because the code compiles without an error but then i get access violation message when debugging. many thanks